# How to change the redirect method and payload that Laravel's validate return?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with validation - if validation fails I get an error.

```
Route::get('list', 'MainController@list');
Route::post('search', 'MainController@search');
Route::post('create', 'MainController@create');
```

`list` shows the full item list and a search form. The form posts to `search`. `search` returns a list of items (search results) and the form with two buttons - either search again or create new item. This form posts to `create` but it calls `search` method if Search button was pressed. If form was submitted using Create button, the input is validated. This is simplified version of my `create` method:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('search'))
        return $this->search($request);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);

    return 0;
}
```

If `search` was clicked it all works. If validation passes it all works (and I can include the logic instead of `return 0;`). But if validation fails I get the following error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:
in RouteCollection.php line 219
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 206
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 802
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 654
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Problem seems to be tied to routing and indeed browsers debugger shows that it's sending a GET request.

I tried to investigate Laravel's validator implementation but couldn't really understand the flow and find where the request is returned. Is there any chance to affect it in a way so that client gets the result of previous POST again?

If I try to allow GET requests on my `search`, problem is partially solved. If I search from the full list and then click Create, validation returns me to `search` again. With no results though so I should still implement some kind of "if validation fails, process this as search request". Well, ok, but I still need what was posted...

If, however, I use the Search again button which posts to `create` and returns the same view, the validator redirects to GET the `create` route which gives me more problems to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your create and your search actions both have their own form, with a distinct action url (or route) associated to them. Could it be that your create button doesn't post to the /create route, but to something different?

Moreover, if you make sure both have their own form, the call to `$this->search()`from within your create method won't be necessary; the router will route both post calls to the proper method.

Comment: Create and search have the same form and action url, but even if I had only a search action with validation, I would have had the same problem. It seems that $this->validate() will not return you to previous view if you got there by doing a POST and the route is not accessible with a GET request.

Comment: Take a look at the ValidatesRequests trait.
You could override an appropriate method in your controller, e.g. buildFailedValidationResponse() or getRedirectUrl(), according to your needs.

Comment: But I think it'd be more robust to do it manually, like you explained in your own answer.
That, or considering to indeed create a GET route for your search url, which could also be used to display the search results after POSTing to search (and then redirecting to this GET route for the results). I would prefer using GET for displaying results over POST anyways. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing to solve the problem is to check manually and if failed - flash errors and redirect the Request to search method:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($request->has('search') || $validation->fails())
        return $this->search($request)->withErrors($validation);

    return 0;
}
```

I was a bit surprised that I could just add `->withErrors()` to the method call and it actually flashes errors to the session. If I knew that researching and flashing errors is this easy with manual validation, I wouldn't even ask this question.

However, now that it's posted, question remains - can you adjust the redirect made by method `$this->validate()` that you get from `ValidatesRequests` trait?

Knowing that you can adjust errorBag naming by creating a FormRequest makes me think that there might be an option for this, just not documented...